# Cannot set environment variables for react app inside node.js app. (heroku)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, environment-variables

So I'm deploying a MERN stack app to heroku, and I have two .env files. One is for the nodejs backend, and one is for the react frontend. In heroku, you can set environment variables but they act essentially as a .env file in the root directory. However, my client folder is nested inside the node.js

Comment: Hi, please provide some code and error logs

Comment: Hi Mahesh Natamai, how did you solve this issue? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `react-scripts`, you just need to preface any React env variables with `REACT_APP_`.  This is how it knows where they belong when it is building your app.  So just add them to your code and to the config vars on Heroku as `REACT_APP_NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV_VAR` and you should be good.

Here's the docs from [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) on how to do it using `react-scripts` and adding the env variables and here it is for [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't know that heroku config variables get passed down to the react app.

Comment: Hi, how are you getting the Heroku env variables to be passed down? I can't get access to any in React which is in the client folder. The variables in Heroku are already prefixed with REACT_APP_ and have dotenv package in both root and client folder. Any help appreicated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I missed to add the following line in the package.json script

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true npm run build --prefix web_client"
```